# How to Write JavaScript for Templated Markup?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, templates

I'm a little stuck on this.

I've been assigned changes to make to an ASP.NET project. The WebForm I'm working on needs to dynamically display and hide controls in response to user actions.

So far, so good. My approach would be to create a little JavaScript. However, on this page, the markup is part of a template for a Telerik control (which I know nothing about). I'm not sure the ramifications of this. Can I still use JavaScript for templated markup?

I tried to insert some existing JavaScript in the page. The first problem I have is my use of `<%= ControlName.ClientID %>`, which produces an error because the name of the control in the template is not seen to exist by ASP.NET.

Is there another way to do this, or am I just going to run into more problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For template controls like repeater you should hook up the javascript from isnide the itembound event. Get the control using FindControl for each row and then register the javascript from code behind. I believe your telerik control should expose something similar to the itembound event that get called for every row..

Comment: By "hook up the javascript", I assume you are talking about setting the onclick attribute. That's fine but my first problem is that I can't easily determine the ClientID of the controls in order to write the functions that will be called. There may be ways to do with the Telerik control but I don't know how to use them and don't have the docs.